# Update records with timestamp where clause with Hibernate HQL

Tags: oracle, hibernate, timestamp, hql, timestamp-with-timezone

I wrote a query with Hibernate HQL that updates some records with timestamp columns:

where clause:

```
creationTime >= :creationTimeFrom and creationTime <= :creationTimeTo
```

set Parameters:

```
query.setDate("creationTimeFrom", creationTimeFrom);
query.setDate("creationTimeTo", creationTimeTo);
```

In some cases the result of query don't match with records correctly and some records dont't update,

I guess the problem is about timezone.The oracle server timezone is set to UTC. but the timezone of client is different.

Comment: In ANSI SQL, `ts BETWEEN a AND b` is identical to `ts >= a AND ts <= b`, and I would assume the same in HQL, which just gets translated to some SQL dialect anyway.  So, I don't think this is your problem.

Comment: Yes, ts BETWEEN a AND b is identical to ts >= a AND ts <= b.I try it. maybe the problem is about timezone. the oracle server timezone is set to UTC, but the the timezone of client is different.

Comment: The post was updated.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your `creationTime` have a time associated with date. Then try to cast `creationTime` to format without time. Something like `creationTime(to_date(column,'DD-MM-YYYY'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use deprecated class in my HQL code.
I fix that and problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to set explicitly the TimeZone, otherwise the default JVM Calendar is used.

```
TimeZone.setDefault( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );
```

Starting from Hibernate 5.2.3:

```
settings.put(
    AvailableSettings.JDBC_TIME_ZONE,
    TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" )
);
```

Reference: [jdbc-time-zone-configuration-property:](http://in.relation.to/2016/09/12/jdbc-time-zone-configuration-property/)